# ArcGIS Online app multiple comments on one feature

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online

I am working on an ArcGIS application that would allow the public to comment on bus routes though a map based interface. The original thought was to use the group sort tool to easily navigate through the routes and use the edit tool to leave comments, but I believe that this would be a bit confusing for the public.

What I would like to accomplish is an application that when you clicked on the route the pop-up would give you the option to leave a comment either right in the initial pop-up or a link to an additional pop-up.

It seems like the application would be in between the edit application and the geoform application.

Has anyone built something like this before

Comment: You could try and use http://solutions.arcgis.com/local-government/help/crowdsource-reporter/

Answer (score 1):

Few different approaches you could achieve this. Two ideas below that you could look into:

**Web AppBuilder and Related Records**

1. Setup a separate related table against your routes. (i.e. 1 to many)
2. Publish to a hosted feature service, disable ability to update geometries and just allow edits to attributes.
3. Add the Editor Widget to Web AppBuilder and configure it to allow inserting new records in the related table.

[image]
[source](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2016/09/14/whats-new-in-web-appbuilder-for-arcgis-september-2016/)

**Combination of Web AppBuilder and GeoForm Template.**

This would be a good option if you want to capture a series of questions from the end user in a form based interface.

1. Calculate midpoint of each route and add this XY information to each route.
2. Web Map with a popup that launches Geoform App URL in a new tab, but also includes the lat/lon from step 1.
3. Have a web app (could be AppBuilder, or a suitable Web App template).
4. The popup launches GeoForm using [a dynamic URL parameter](https://github.com/Esri/geoform-template-js/issues/351) to create a new record at that location. Hide the URL from the user behind some friendly text like 'Submit Feedback about this Route'
5. Optionally hide other records created by other users in the GeoForm app
6. Gather feedback as a new point at that location.

Variation on this might be to not use lat/lons, but use URL parameters for feature layer searches setup against your routes layer by the route ID. 
Search for areas of land they want to comment on (via a layer level search setup on the webmap) - see searchLayers in the defaults.config

[Here is an example](http://melbournewater.maps.arcgis.com/apps/MapJournal/index.html?appid=e60e956c9f304027802e9bef6177fac1) that is not actually complete - the URL parameter has not been setup to load Geoform at the same record that was just selected but it is possible.